# Move incremental data (CDC) from Amazon RDS to Redshift?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-redshift, amazon-rds, amazon-aurora

I have a requirement to move incremental data from Amazon Aurora Postgres to Amazon Redshift. This will be a daily job. New data will be inserted into Redshift and if there is a change in existing data it will be updated. Any recommendations for doing this?

Answer (score 2):

There are 2 methods for doing this by AWS services.

Your first option is looking at [DMS](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/dms/latest/userguide/CHAP_Target.Redshift.html), using the Postgres dB as the source and the redshift dB as the target. After performing a one time import you can perform imports of the differential between the last run.

Your second option is to look at [data pipeline](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/datapipeline/latest/DeveloperGuide/dp-copydata-redshift.html) to build an incremental pipeline.

Comment: Thanks Chris for the suggestion! DMS or Datapipeline is going to be a straight dump. I might be adding few transformation logic on the data present in RDS and move it to Redshift. Can you please let me know if there is a way?

Comment: DMS does support some transformations: https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/transformations-aws-dms/. Outside of that you could export the differential to kinesis firehouse and then use lambda transformation on it before it goes to Redshift